# Editable using reference for a TextChangedListener

Tags: android, xamarin, textchanged, using-directives

In Xamarin, may I have some help to write some code for a TextChangedListener for an EditText object?

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class InputTextWatcher
{
    public void afterTextChanged (Editable s)
    {

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }

    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {

    }
}
```

This is the error that I am getting:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Editable' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to implement ITextWatcher:

```
using Android.Text;

public class InputTextWatcher : : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
{
    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    public void BeforeTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    public void OnTextChanged(Java.Lang.ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

You should also consider using the event handlers instead:

```
        editText.BeforeTextChanged += HandleBeforeTextChanged;

        // or
        editText.TextChanged += (sender, e) => 
        {

        };
    }

    void HandleBeforeTextChanged (object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```